# Xcode upgrade/Swift 2 to 3 migration broke storyboard outlet connections, how can I fix them all at once?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode-storyboard

All of my storyboard connections to my Swift files have been broken by an Xcode upgrade to migrate to Swift 3. Here's a sample screenshot

[image]

We can see the circles not filled out. Normally I could fix this by loading the storyboard then going back to the files, but this isn't working now. When I run the app, it crashes with "invalid selector". I've been fixing them one-by-one by dragging new connections to my files, but this is taking an excessive amount of time. Is there a way to repair the connections?

For reference I am now on Xcode 8.3.3, I believe I was on 7 before

Comment: The migrator does not touch IB outlets and actions (the circles don't indicate the state reliably). However I suspect that the reason is related to the changed `selector` syntax.

Comment: I fixed the first selector error by just making a new IBAction connection with a new method name, then moving the logic into the new method. I didn't actually call this method with a selector anywhere in code. I think you're right, I just don't know what I can do about it

Comment: Also I think I should note I didn't use any built-in migrator functionality. I just downloaded the new Xcode and manually updated my methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the new unnamed first-parameter change

For example, change

```
@IBAction func segmentSwitched(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
```

to

```
@IBAction func segmentSwitched(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
```

Reload the storyboard and rebuild